# Javascript, passing on a mouse event

Tags: javascript, dom

I would like a cross modern browser way to take a mouse event from one html element and pass it on to another.

eg.

```
el1.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  el2.trigger('mousemove', e);
});

el2.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
   //THIS SHOULD BE CALLED WHEN EITHER el1
});
```

a jquery solution is ok but I would prefer a non-jquery solution.  Is this simple?

Comment: Your event listener code is already restricted to modern browsers only

Comment: good point, was just trying to explain the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the correct code

```
var el1 = document.getElementById('el1');
var el2 = document.getElementById('el2');

el1.onmousemove = function(e) {
    alert('el1 event');
    el2.onmousemove(e);
};
el2.onmousemove = function(e) {    
    alert('el2 event');
};
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7ncqq/)

This is good if you want the event argument `e` to pass over to `el2`'s event. This updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7ncqq/2/) shows mouse position being passed over.

Answer (score 0):

If you accept a jQuery answer then here's the code:

```
// el1 and el2 are the jQuery objects of the DOM elements
el1.mousemove(function (event) {
    el2.mousemove(event);
});
```

In pure javascript:

```
el1.onmousemove = function(e) {
    el2.onmousemove('mousemove', e);
};

el2.onmousemove = function(e) {

};
```

Comment: `element.trigger()` is not a valid method. This is jQuery proprietary function. it would serve better in the first part of your answer, dispatchEvent is the native DOM api method.

Comment: @rlemon good point, I copy pasted the jQuery code that I gave and forgot to change it. It is fixed thanks for noticing

Answer (score 0):

```
el1.addEventListener('mousemove', handler, false);
el2.addEventListener('mousemove', handler2, false);
function handler(e) {
    // do some stuff
    handler2.call(el2, e); // pass el2 as this reference, event as the argument.
};
```

not too sure if this is what you are looking for, just name the event handlers and trigger the one off the other.

if you do not need the `this` reference in the second handler, use `handler2(e);` instead.

further readings:
[Function.prototype.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

[Here is a half-baked demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/DPcb9/) passing the mouse event args. I'm unsure how well supported layerX/Y is, I just used it to show the demo.

Answer (score 0):

native should work like that

```
var evt;
el1.onmousemove = function() {
  evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvent');
  evt.initEvent('mousemove', true, true);
  el2.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

You can read up on `element.dispatchEvent` here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.dispatchEvent

Comment: nice, I like this. I didn't remember dispatchEvent ;)

Comment: how do you get the mouse coordinates into the event? so that you can pass them on.